# Concatenate elements from a list based on a criteria

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Let's say we have the list

```
L = ['a', '!b', '!c', 'd', 'e', '!f', 'g', 'h']
```

and we want to concatenate each element with the previous one if it starts with `!`.

Expected output:

```
M = ['a!b!c', 'd', 'e!f', 'g', 'h']
```

This works but it's probably unnecessarily complex to `join` the list into a string, and then to re-split the string into a list:

```
M = ''.join(('' if l.startswith('!') else '\n') + l for l in L).splitlines()[1:]
# ['a!b!c', 'd', 'e!f', 'g', 'h']
```

Is there a simpler way to concatenate elements from a list based on a criteria (`'!' in l`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are looking for a one-liner, but how about this not too complicated loop?

```
L = ['a', '!b', '!c', 'd', 'e', '!f', 'g', 'h']
M = []
for x in L:
    if x.startswith("!"):
        M[-1] += x
    else:
        M.append(x)
# ['a!b!c', 'd', 'e!f', 'g', 'h']
```

If you prefer short to readable, you *could* use a ternary using `pop`...

```
for x in L:
    M.append(M.pop() + x if x.startswith("!") else x)
```

I thought a bit more about a "clever" one-line solution with `reduce`, `groupby`, `takewhile`, or "join-and-split" solutions like the one you have, but if they work at all they just make it more complicated. I think this is one of those cases where if you want a one-liner, you should just define a function for it.

Comment: Nice indeed, this is more classical way without a list comprehension. Preferably, I'd be interested in a one liner if possible :)

Comment: I also *feel* like this should be possible with `groupby`, but the tricky part is that you have to join the "borders" between the groups (atleast if you use `.startswith('!')` as the key)

Comment: If I may suggest a tiny edit to the second one, just so it doesn't break if the first element starts with `!`: `M.append(M.pop() + x if M and x.startswith("!") else x)`

Comment: I am trying with `groupby`, but it's becoming really nasty. I think explicit `for` loop is much better to achieve this

Comment: I was going to post something similar but you beat me to it. Likewise I took a look at `groupby` and `reduce` but the complexity far outweighs the one-line-ability. The best I could come up with was the adaptation of OPs original (join/split) idea but I really think that the simple for loop (encased in a function if required) is the best solution. You have my vote...

Answer (score 3):

As a slightly more compact version of your join and split one-liner, if your elements are single characters (or something matchable with a well-defined regex), you can join into a string and then use `re.findall` to match the parts with `!` in them:

```py
import re

L = ['a', '!b', '!c', 'd', 'e', '!f', 'g', 'h']
print(re.findall('([a-z](?:![a-z])*)', ''.join(L)))
```

Output

```
['a!b!c', 'd', 'e!f', 'g', 'h']
```

If your list is actually comprised of elements more complex than single characters you would replace `[a-z]` in the regex (two places) with a regex that matched those elements.

Comment: Nice solution! But each element of L could have multiple chars and ! inside them. The criteria is only "starts by !".

Comment: @Basj Can you give some sample data? I don't think `!` inside the values is an issue because those values will remain joined in the `findall`. It may be as simple as changing `[a-z]` to `[a-z]+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the elements, then remove the separators before '!' and split again:

```
L = ['a', '!b', '!c', 'd', 'e', '!f', 'g', 'h']

M = ",".join(L).replace(",!","!").split(",")

print(M)

# ['a!b!c', 'd', 'e!f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: Nice solution indeed!